# Install arch with linux-lts

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

I wanted to install Arch with LTS kernel so I changed the line
`# pacstrap -K /mnt base linux linux-firmware` with
`# pacstrap -K /mnt base linux-lts linux-firmware` but then I got some errors and my installtion failed. So my question is : can I install the Arch with only LTS kernel or I have to first install the latest kernel and then switch to the LTS?

Comment: It should work - what errors did you get?

Comment: not remember exactly but was some signature error. all packages were downloaded. but got error on installation. I'll try to post the errors when I try again and if I get them again.. Thanks @frostschutz

Comment: Yes it works, the problem was the signature error . because I was using old arch iso to install. So I install the arch-keyring package and It worked.